# How to implement a logout when using form based security

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6

I use a JDBC form based security realm, and i want to implement a logout, but when i click on the link i see this exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.AccessControlException:
>   access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission
>   suppressAccessChecks) ... Caused by:
>   java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks)

This is the EJB i created to do the loggout:

```
@Stateless(name = "ejbs/SessionSupportEJBImpl")
@DeclareRoles({"administrators","users"})
public class SessionSupportEJBImpl implements SessionSupportEJB {

    @PermitAll
    public void releaseUserState() {
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Here i call it from a backing bean:

```
@Named("logoutBB")
@RequestScoped
public class LogoutBean {

    @EJB
    private SessionSupportEJB sessionSupportEJB;

    public String logout() {
        sessionSupportEJB.releaseUserState();
        return "index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

And here the markup that should trigger it:

```
<h:form>
        <h:commandLink value="LOGOUT" action="#{logoutBB.releaseUserState}"/>
    </h:form>
```

My doubts are:

- How can make the logout feature work ?
- Is is it mandatory  to use the ejbs security annotations always on my  EJBs to permit access?(When using a security realm)
- Should i do this with a servlet instead of an EJB?
- Is this approach wrong, should i try something else for the logout?

Comment: This is probably related to your question, but I'm not sure. How is your EJB getting access to the `FacesContext` instance? I personally don't think that a HTTP protocol specific object like `HttPSession` should be accessed in an EJB container. It is a case where the concerns are not separated. It would be better to implement the logout mechanism in a managed bean.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds I dont know, maybe this is not correct.I moved the logout mechanism to the managed bean instead of the EJB, but i get the same error(I will paste the full stack trace above). What do you think is the best practice to do the logout? Maybe i should not do it this way?

Comment: In LogoutBean class, why are you injecting sessionSupportEJB and not SessionSupportEJBImpl ?

Comment: @perissf  because i program to an interface not a realization. CDI will instantiate for me behind the scene

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In first place my recommendation is that you don't invoke FacesContext in EJB because the FacesContext is an element of the "View Layer". The purpose of EJB are represent the "Bussines Logic Layer" and a best practice is to have the bussines logic isolated from de View because you can access to the bussines logic from many types of views.

About how to close the session, I suggest do the following:

Create a servlet and implement the method doGet in order to close the session as follows:

```
@WebServlet("/logout")
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpSession session= req.getSession();
        session.invalidate();
        RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/login.xhtml"); //The url where go after logout
        rd.forward(req,res);
  }
}
```

So you can add the following link in you html / xhtml pages for logout:

```
<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
```

If you are using JSF, for get the context path of you app, you can use:

```
<a href="${request.contextPath}/logout">Logout</a>
```

DISCLAIMER: I'm assuming that you are using Java EE 6. Also I don't tested the code (but I know that it works) if you have some problems of compilation please let me know

Comment: I will give it a try, and i let you know. I just have a little doubt. Because i use jsf, i need to use `h:commandLink` instead of `<a>`, when the returned value from the link is `/logout` , the servlet will know that needs to process that request right? Can the servlet do it by detecting the id of the component that triggered the action?(So /logout does not appear in the url)

Comment: Since the implementation is in a servlet you don't need use a h:commandLink, <a> will work fine. When the application requests /logout the servlet invalidates the session and redirect to user to "/login.xhtml" you can put your desired URI here. About your last point, you can send additional parameters to Servlet, change the URL mapping, and procees in doPost.

Comment: I think im close, but i get redirected to `http://localhost:8080/logout` and i get an error 404(Cannot find resource), i think the mistake is here: `req.getRequestDispatcher("/login.xhtml");`

Comment: The problem is with the <a> tag. If you are using jsf you can replace ti for: <a href="${request.contextPath}/logout">Logout</a>

Comment: I managed to do it. This way is a way more simple than what i was going to do. Thanks!